# Replacing Pivot Table with Values to Filter and Delete Rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to build a spreadsheet around some data coming from a pivot table, but I cannot filter and delete rows.

I've tried `.Value = .Value` for the table but I am getting the error message

> "We can't make this change for the selected cells because it will affect a PivotTable..." (Run-time error '1004')

```
    With ws
        FinalRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("B1:C" & FinalRow)'Pivot table range
            .Value = .Value
        End With

        For iCntr = FinalRow To 1 Step -1
            If Rows(iCntr).Hidden Then
                Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next iCntr
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just `.Value` the range like that. You need to remove the pivot - by perhaps storing the data, clearing the range and then re-writing the data.

Try this:

```
Dim tmp As Variant
With ws
    FinalRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("B1:C" & FinalRow) 'Pivot table range
        tmp = .Value
        .ClearContents
        .Value = tmp
    End With
End With
```

Incidentally, if you've 'hidden' items in the pivot, they're removed from the table, not actually hidden - so I suspect there will be no need to delete afterwards..

Comment: So the     `.ClearContents` line is not working (Giving me the same error as above). Tried deleting the Pivot table all together and I'm getting the same problem: `.Range(Pt.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: Then your range `"B1:C" & FinalRow` isn't covering the entire pivot table..? Maybe you've got a total at the bottom of column C with nothing next to it in B? Or it spans more than just B and C columns?

Comment: Seems to me like it is - Pivot table actually starts in B2 but otherwise it is within range. Also my `delete` line is outside of the `with.range` so it should be covering the entire range exactly

Comment: You might check the value of `FinalRow` - to ensure it's getting to the bottom of the table. You could also try just `Range("B:C").ClearContents` - if that doesn't work, there must be part of the pivot outside those two columns.

Comment: Just threw in `.Cells.ClearContents` for the entire ws and I'm still getting that pivot table error unfortunately

Comment: Maybe try `.ClearTable`, *then* `.ClearContents`

Comment: I don't know why by this pivot table is REFUSING to be deleted. Only workaround I've found is sending it to a new sheet and deleting that. Thanks for your help though!